# How to export react JS material-ui table data with pagination into csv, excel and pdf?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am a new front end developer. I am trying to create buttons on front end which can export material-ui table data with pagination into csv, excel and pdf. Is there any library which I can use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have good experience using [ExcelJS](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs) library which not only supports CSV output, but also Excel and other formats.  The API is incredibly easy to use, and it also saves you from figuring out how to escape the characters.  ExcelJS should work well if you look into file generation in browser or server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know the source of your table data (an array of objects) there are some libraries that you can use to convert from that array into a [pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf), [xls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx). For CSV you could make something like

```
const rows = [
    ["name1", "city1", "some other info"],
    ["name2", "city2", "more info"]
];

let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";

rows.forEach(function(rowArray) {
    let row = rowArray.join(",");
    csvContent += row + "\r\n";
});
```

Then you only have to "open" your generated file into a new window like

```
const encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
window.open(encodedUri);
```